# Determine the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ where $a_n=\frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Determine the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ where $a_n=\frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}$

Now $\alpha=\limsup_{n\to \infty}(\vert a_n\vert)^\frac{1}{n}$ and so radius of convergence $R=\frac{1}{\alpha}$

So now $\alpha=\limsup_{n\to \infty}(\vert a_n\vert)^\frac{1}{n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}  (\vert \frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}\vert)^\frac{1}{n}$

Now I know $lim_{n\to\infty} n^\frac{1}{n}=1$ but what about the denominator?

Comment: Try proving $4^na_n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: $3n$ grows far slower than $4^n$, so it can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$$a^n=4^{-n}\frac{n^2}{1+3n4^{-n}},$$and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac14\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^2}{1+3n4^{-n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac14\frac{\sqrt[n]n^2}{\sqrt[n]{1+3n4^{-n}}}=\frac14.$$Therefore, the radius of convergence is $4$.

Comment: Duplicate target found instantly with Approach0.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\sum b_nz^n$ and $\sum n^2b_nz^n$ have same radius of convergence so set $b_n=\dfrac 1{4^n+3n}$

Also since $0\le 3n\le 3\times 4^n$ then $\dfrac 1{4^{n+1}}\le b_n\le \dfrac 1{4^n}$ both bounds leading to a radius of convergence of $4$.

It is often faster to work out simple inequalities rather than setting for calculations.